# java.lang.IllegalStateExeption: Expectet a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 16 path $[0].questions

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I looked at some other threads about this topic and integrated the solution it offered but it still throws the same error. this is the first time i try to call an api on android. here i want to 'GET' an array of objects. There is no stack trace since the app does not crash. i think the problem has to do with the array of questions.

```
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.100:3000/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
        Call<List<Post>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getPosts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                    textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }

                List<Post> posts = response.body();

                for (Post post : posts){
                    String content = "";
                    content += "Doctor: " + post.getDoctor() + "\n";
                    content += "Name: " + post.getName() + "\n";
                    content += "Questions: " + post.getQuestions() + "\n\n";

                    textViewResult.append(content);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
                textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

here is an example of the json data:

```
  [
    {
      "questions":[...],
      "_id":"5f42954a7e252b48ec3564b6",
      "name":"Lifestyle",
      "doctor":"doctoremail@gmail.com",
      "__v":0
    },
    {
      "questions":[...],
      "_id":"5f4299687e252b48ec3564b7",
      "name":"Headache",
      "doctor":"doctoremail@gmail.com",
      "__v":0
    },
    {
      "questions":[...],
      "_id":"5f429b2f7e252b48ec3564b9",
      "name":"Foot pain",
      "doctor":"doctoremail@gmail.com",
      "__v":0
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and update it with json data and full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. the problem was that the 'questions' property in my model was of type string in stead of List String

```
package com.example.medlog;

import java.util.List;

public class Post {
    private String name;
    private String doctor;
    private List<String> questions;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDoctor() {
        return doctor;
    }

    public List<String> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }
}
```